# Require Authentication while Accessing WSDL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, visualrules

I have developed a Rule Service in Visual Rule. We can expose or deploy this rule as Web Service(WSDL). I have deployed that on my system(localhost). One of my colleague wants to use that WSDL file. But it is asking for "HTTP authentication" with Username and Password. I am not getting which UserName and Password it is asking for.

I deploy webservices on Tomcat server.
I can access the same WSDL with below address on my machine.  But my colleague couldn't.
" http://10.164.98.48:8087/executionserver/services/cbeaa370-c11d-11e1-8ba8-d4bed92ae488/DotNetRuleCal/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/DotNetRuleCal.wsdl "

Help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for your appreciable solutions. 
I got the solution. We just need to pass correct credentials to access WSDL from other machines. 

I was trying to connect only with  "UserName" & "Password". In case of multiple tenancy we have to specify "tenant" name also. So in username field I passed ***<< TenantName\username >>***, and passed correct ***password***.

Thank you **stackoverflow**.

Answer (score 0):

You have certainly configured the basic authentification while developping you webservice.
Check you code, you'll probably find your Username/Password.

What can explain that your collegues can't acces unlik you, is that you have maybe saved your credential in you navigator.
Try with another navigator or delete your data acces stored in your main navigator.

Answer (score 0):

It could be a Tomcat configuration thing. Open the `server.xml` file inside the `conf` directory and add this to the `Connector` tag: `address="10.164.98.48"`. Hope that works.

BTW, to be sure that your local machine is indeed not requiring credentials, open that page in incognito mode in Chrome (it will not read previously stored credentials).

Comment: I got solution. We just need to pass credentials while accessing the WSDL.